# Errors in Android Studio and emulators problem

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Can anybody please tell me what this means and how to fix it?

```
Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor:56460 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)
Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 56876 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)
```

In general, my Android studio and Emulator act like jerk. I am new and I don't know much about this kind of problems.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)